# How do I stop a python script thats been deleted [Mac]

Tags: python

Basically I used a python script to block websites w Python on a Mac, now the person deleted the file, and cant stop it from blocking the site.

Edit:
None of the solutions seem to work, Python is not showing up in activity monitor, and pgrep- a python shows nothing. Still need help please, a restart did nothing.

Comment: This is probably better suited for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Answer (score 0):

A program running has its own memory space and isn't affected much if any source files are deleted. If you want to force end the process, open Activity Monitor (/Applications/Utilities) and search for `python`. If you don't find anything, search for the name of the file and any other relevant keywords you can use to locate the PID of the process. Then run the following:

```py
import os
PID = process_id_goes_here
os.system(f'kill -9 {PID}')
```

which will force kill the process.

Comment: I mean, if you are going to open the Activity Monitor you might as well just use it to kill the process.

Comment: Yes, but kill (9) is much stronger and unavoidable, unlike some processes that do not respond to force quit (15)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on https://stackoverflow.com/a/61787352/5666087, you can find the process and kill it in the terminal. So in a terminal, run the following:

```
pgrep -a python  # find the process
kill PID  # kill it using the PID found with the command above
```

Answer (score 0):

Find process Id for the running script and kill it.

#### Find PID

```
$ ps -x | grep -i "python" | grep -v grep
```

#### Kill the process. I.e., to kill a process with PID 61497, you do.

```
$ kill -9 61497
```

You can also restart your Mac, the process will be killed. It will only start in its own. Only if it's there is a line in you bash_profile( i,e,. python someScript.py) that tells it to do so at boot/login.